# Real part of a rational curve

Tags: algebraic-curves

Let $C\subset\mathbb{P}^2$  be a rational curve of degree $d$. Let $k$ be the number of real places at infinity of $C$ Now, does that mean that there exists a rational parametrization of $C$ in which the denominator can be chosen to have at most $k$ real roots?